# How to check if different values are not in an array using JQuery inArray?

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have written some code that checks if an array exists and if not, creates one called window.list

It then checks if the array contains a 2 or a 3 value and if not adds them to the list.

if they are within the list already it outputs "Value is already in the list!" then breaks out of the function.

When I execute the code it only recognises the first clause of inArray that checks for  a 2 value.
3 does not function. I would like the ability to add more values in the future. I'm not sure this is the most efficient way to write this query.

```
if (typeof window.list == "undefined" || !(window.list instanceof Array)) {
    window.list = new Array;
}

if ($.inArray(2, window.list) == -1 || $.inArray(3, window.list) == -1) {
    window.list.push(presentationId);
} else {
    console.log("Value is already in the list!")
    return;
}
```

Comment: What's the value of `presentationId`?

Comment: it will be 2 or 3 depending on another form.

Comment: Seems like the check could just be: `if ($.inArray(presentationId, window.list) === -1) { window.list.push(presentationId) } ...` This way you don't need to care what `presentationId` *could* be in the future (better for maintenance).

Comment: @Cory That would make more sense. If `presentationId` is `2`, you don't want to add it twice just because `3` isn't in the array. Though without knowing how this code is being called it's difficult to know what the problem they're experiencing is being caused by; if `$.inArray(2, window.list) == -1` is false it should check for the presence of `3` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could merge the arrays and leave just the unique values with jQuery

```
window.list = [2,3];

window.list = $.merge(window.list, [2,3,7,2,60]);
window.list = $.unique(window.list);

//OUTPUT: window.list = [2,3,7,60];
```

[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/codepic/gFmqt/)

---

**OR if you want to check an array against an array and operate on the found / not found instances.** You could make a simple plugin [Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/codepic/vbkEC/)

Your plugin

```
(function ($) {
  $.fn.Contains = function(value, success, failure) {
      var arr = this;
      if(value instanceof Array){
          $(value).each(function(i,item){
              var found = $.inArray(item, arr) > -1;
              if (found){
                  success(item);
              } else {
                  failure(item);
              }
        });
      }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Then call it like:

```
window.list = [2,3];

$(window.list).Contains([2, 3, 6, 7], function(foundValue){
    // Handle the foundValue here
    alert('found: ' + foundValue);
}, function(missingValue){
    // Handle the missingValue here
    alert('missing: ' + missingValue);
});
```

---

**Or if you want to use a custom plugin to merge the distinct values to one array with one call**, you could do the following [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/codepic/nkhQa/):

```
// Your plugin to merge the distinct values
(function ($) {
  $.fn.MergeDistinct = function(value) {
      var arr = this;
      if(value instanceof Array){
          $(value).each(function(i,item){
              var found = $.inArray(item, arr) > -1;
              if (!found) arr.push(item);
        });
      }
      return arr;
  };
})(jQuery);

// Your list of items
window.list = [2,3];

// Merge the new values without creating duplicates
window.list = $(window.list).MergeDistinct([2, 3, 6, 7]);

//OUTPUT: window.list = [2,3,6,7];
```

Comment: Hey, great thanks. How can I turn the method call into an if statement?

Comment: $(window.list).Contains([0, 1, 2, 3 ], function(foundValue){
console.log("item found"); })

Comment: Also how is missingValue called in your JSfiddle? I don't see it mentioned anywhere else in the code.

Comment: The code is calling success(item); for the item found in the original array and failure(item); for the item not present in the original array.

Comment: How could I convert the function call to an if statement to perform an action based on if no numbers match the array?

Comment: You don't need an if in the example. All the values passed into function(missingValue){} are values that are not present in the array and all the values passed into function(foundValue){  } are values that are present in the array.

Comment: I don't need to act if the numbers don't match.

Comment: I need an if statement because I need to perform one action if the numbers match and a different one if they dont. This example performs both anyway. Also I don't want to loop through each matching number.

Comment: Simply modify the if (found) as needed. If you return false; the $.each will stop looping

Comment: ok ive wrapped my code in the else clause of the if(found) statement. However I need the code to break if it finds just one matching value. At the moment it has to find all four to work properly.

Comment: Like I said, simply retun false whenever you want to break out from the loop.

Answer (score 2):

If the presentationID is 2 or 3 why don't you try the code like this:

```
...
if ($.inArray(presentationID, window.list) == -1) {
    window.list.push(presentationId);
} else {
...
```